# image uploading too slow php

Tags: php, ajax, performance, image-upload

i am doing multiple image upload with php using ajax . i am submitting the image upload form with file inputs targetted to a hidden iframe . 
       after that i do 'move_uploaded_file()' and then i am compressing the uploaded file to a smaller size. 
       then i display the uloaded file names in iframe and retrieve them in jquery to check whether all were uploaded. 
       after all these processes i am doing database actions and building some html content and display them . this really takes plenty of time while running in my machine itself . i felt it will surely take too much time when it is live.
       please suggest me some way to shorten this lengthy time and correct me if i am wrong in this process. i understood that compression takes much time . but i have to compress it and i have no other go .

Comment: What kind of database actions are you performing? Compression can be slow but a slow database connection can also be the issue here.

Comment: i am using mysql database. but i checked it by removing the compression function . it was at good speed . it gets slower only when i include the compression function

Comment: What file type (image format) are you handling? Or better, what do you mean by *compressing*? Do you actually compress the image, or are you recalculating the image dimensions?

Comment: @asha And my second question?

Comment: @yoshi i calculate new widths and heights and then recreate the image using 'imagecopyresampled()' and 'imagejpeg()' functions . i checked for the new image size too . it was reduced to few kbs.

Comment: @asha So, basically what's taking up the time, is recalculating the image dimensions?! Could you add that to your question? As *compression* is a bit misleading here.
Is it crucial that you resize the images on the fly? Or could you move that to another request? Maybe on first display of the image (that's how I do it)?

Comment: @yoshi anyhow i'll post my code . but i'll try out ur method of displaying first and doing the resizing work later . anyway thanks

Comment: guys in my case i am using 'move_uploaded_file()' for security stuff . so it gets loaded to server . i am doing 'imagejpeg()' on the uploaded file and replacing the same file. is anything wrong with this ?

Comment: You could also limit your uploaded file size to let's say 200 KB, this way you don't have to resize only to get smaller files.

Answer (score 0):

also , if you want multiple async ajax requests, you should take a look at http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/  the ideea is to take care when using session_start();